# Network setup issues

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have two routers, CenturyLink, and a house that only has a DSL line (8 mbps). The CenturyLink router is a standard C1100Z that has to be hard rebooted regularly (every day or two). I'm not sure if its just overheating or bogged down by use from a house of 3 people or a combination of both. Cascaded off the C1100Z is a Netgear WNDR3700v1 flashed with DD-WRT.

I have tried to setup the Netgear as the main router but neither plain RJ11 into its RJ45 port nor an RJ11 to RJ45 cord off of Amazon would get it to work. The CenturyLink router has RJ11 input so it can connect to the wall.

Are there issues with my current setup? Is there something I am not understanding? I would like to abandon the CenturyLink provided router but I'm not sure if that possible. Does the Netgear require a modem which is why it does not work when connected to the wall?

Comment: ...has to be rebooted... is the very reason why i only buy mikrotik anymore. (I am not affiliated with mikrotik)

Comment: Try connecting the C1100Z's power supply directly into a wall socket, as opposed to a power strip with several other devices.  There might be a ground loop condition that creates electrical interference in sensitive devices.

Comment: There is not a power strip per se but a [two-to-six outlet](https://www.amazon.com/2-Pack-GE-Grounded-Adapter-Six-Outlet-Tap/dp/B071YBMFDL/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1512951735&sr=8-5&keywords=two+to+six+outlet+adapter). Would that still apply?

Answer (score 3):

#### Does the Netgear require a modem which is why it does not work when connected to the wall?

Yes.

The Netgear WNDR3700v1 is not a router/modem so you cannot use it to replace your Modem.

The [System Requirements](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3700V1/wndr3700_ds_17feb10.pdf) make that very clear:

> - Broadband (cable, DSL) Internet service and modem with Ethernet connection

as does the [Setup Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3700V1/WNDR3700_SM_04JUN2010.pdf):

> To connect your N600 wireless gigabit router:
>
> 1. Connect the N600 wireless gigabit router, the computer, and the modem.
>
>    - a. Turn off your computer.
>    - b. Turn off and unplug the cable or ADSL broadband modem. If your modem has a backup battery, remove it as well.
>    - c. Locate the Ethernet cable (1) that connects your computer to the modem.
> 2. Disconnect the cable from the modem (2). You will connect it to the router later.
> 3. Locate the Ethernet cable that came with the NETGEAR product. Securely insert that Ethernet  cable into your modem and into the
>      Internet port of the N600 wireless gigabit router (3).
> 4. Locate the cable you removed from the modem in step 2. Securely insert that cable (4) into a LAN port on the router such as LAN port
>      1.
>
> [image]